# Ember.js Ember.View didRender event

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, ember.js

I building a ember.js app that also ties into some other jQuery plugins. I have some form fields that I need to call a jQuery plugin against once the view is rendered. I've tried hooking into `didInsertElement`, but apparently the values for the bound form fields are not assigned at insertion. Is there a callback in existence for when the view completely renders or when bindings are initialized?

ie.

```
MyView: Ember.View.extend
    #Boaring normal stuff here

    didInsertElement: ->
        $('.some-class').doSomething()
```

and

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="someField" class="some-class"}}
```

Does not work because the values of `.some-class` are a not set yet.

I don't want to use a `setTimeout` and create a race condition.

Comment: Perhaps you can use Ember.run.sync() to force all bindings. But I think there is an other way. Could you post more context, or even better doing a jsfiddle to illustrate. http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/AvgvJ/ as base

Comment: @sly7_7 Thanks, here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AhPyJ/, please ignore the stuff named 'silly', I am a new parent and everything unpleasant is now 'silly'... The plugin that I am using is TinyMCE, but it is not cross domain friendly so I just wrote some didily plugin to exemplify the error.

Comment: I think your code works if you use $('.silly-field'). (you missed the dot). Note that you can access the jquery object of the view, by calling this.$()

Comment: @sly7_7 garbage, it does work doesn't it... Perhaps this is a race condition. My actual code, upon which I am NDA'd is a very large and complex view, perhaps additional complexity causes it. I will try again to reproduce in a fiddle

Comment: @sly7_7 bingo: http://jsfiddle.net/wmarbut/fk6fb/2/ It has to do with the `Ember.TextArea` view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, what is going on, is that the testValue binding is updated after the view is inserted. So what you can do is to call `$('.silly-field').doSomethingSilly();` inside an `Ember.run.next()` function.

As written in the docs:

```
Ember.run(myContext, function(){
 // code to be executed in the next RunLoop, which will be scheduled after the current one
});
```

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle for anyone who wants to see this implemented http://jsfiddle.net/wmarbut/fk6fb/3/