# emberjs and foundation4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, zurb-foundation, zepto

i am trying to use emberjs and foundation 4 which is now using the zepto framework, though as soon as i added the emberjs includes into my application.js the foundation code stops working. is there something wrong with the order of the includes?

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require events
//= require foundation
//= require rails.validations
//= require rails
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps

//= require handlebars
//= require ember
//= require ember-data
//= require teammngt

//= require_self
TeamMngt = Ember.Application.create();
$(document).foundation();
```

Comment: There is a chance that the order of requires really matters. You can reorder your `application.js` and tell us about the results, it would be interesting.

Comment: `code stops working`???..there may be a error thrown..can u post the stacktrace or error from console here...

Comment: From what I've worked out the app generated file TeamMNGT made by ember which has a few more includes in it is causing the issues though i haven't worked out which ones exactly

Comment: anyone else been success in getting these 2 to play nicely?

Comment: I am using both of these.  You can specify that foundation uses jquery instead of zepto.

Answer (score 12):

### TL;DR

```
TeamMngt = Ember.Application.create({
  ready: function() {
    Ember.run.next(this, function(){ 
      $(document).foundation(); 
    });
  }
});
```

## OR

Add after you create the application:

```
TeamMngt.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {    
    Ember.run.next(this, function(){ 
      $(document).foundation(); 
    })
  }
});
```

**Note:** Change TeamMngt to whatever you set `= Ember.Application.create();`

---

### Some Explanation:

After your application template gets loaded, `didInsertElement` event gets fired.  But placing `$(document).foundation()` there alone won't work (I'm guessing the way things are loaded/bound or whatever).  So I did:

```
didInsertElement: function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(document).foundation();
  }, 0);
}
```

Having a `setTimeout()` with 0ms seemed weird, so I figured there is a better way.  Thus, leading to putting `$(document).foundation()` inside `Ember.run.next()`.

---

**Credits:** Zaxnyd
**Reference:** [Ember.js Ember.View didRender event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724350/ember-js-ember-view-didrender-event)

Comment: found this to be useful in conjunction: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18072264/1396904