# Foundation.js dropdown menu in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to use the Foundation framework in an Ember app. The problem I'm having is with the navbar dropdown menu. When placing the Foundation layout in the handlebars template, the navbar no longer works on hover or on click. However, if you shrink the window so the mobile version is displayed, the navbar works on click. I'm pretty sure it's not the Foundation code, because the same code in regular HTML without Ember works.

I checked out [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15861140/emberjs-and-foundation4), but neither worked for me (the first is still in place in my code).

My code can be found [here](https://github.com/emilytrabert/foundation-and-ember), with *index.html* using Ember and *grid.html* not using Ember.

If you have any insights or questions, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dropdown hover behaviour comes from CSS. Ember doesn't play a part in this bug. :)

I noticed `grid.html` uses CSS from the foundation website, while the `index.html` uses CSS from local files. I think you have mismatched versions of foundation's CSS files.

I changed the CSS link tags inside the `index.html` to use the one on foundation as the grid.html does. That fixes the problem.

```
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">-->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">-->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://foundation.zurb.com/page-templates4/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://foundation.zurb.com/page-templates4/css/foundation.css">
```

I would suggest downloading the working CSS from the foundation site, and customizing it from there.

Comment: Well I feel really silly. That was indeed the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually, the problem was css/style.css; deleting it fixed it. But thank you for pointing me in the right direction. :P