# Execute code once after all views have completely rendered in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

Something like document ready, but after all Ember views rendering

I am doing this right now with an override on ApplicationView didInsertElement, which seems to be working so far:

```
App.ApplicationView = Em.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    // Do your magic.
  }
});
```

I am wondering if this is the right way for an Ember document ready, or if Ember has a more native support for this simple and very common thing.

Answer (score 10):

You can easily add a "post render" hook by reopening the base View class and adding it into the render queue.

Here's some code to show you how:

```
Ember.View.reopen({
    didInsertElement : function() {
        this._super();
        Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this.didRenderElement);
    },
    didRenderElement : function() {
        // Override this in your View's
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a step in the right direction. Currently I'm trying to run javascript on the render of the page after any transition or refresh. I tried putting my jquery block in willTransition, didTransition and the before and afterModel hooks in the application route with no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

The `didInsertElement` is the right place, but if you want to be completely sure your render queue is completely flushed you could also listen to the `afterRender` event, something like this:

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, 'processChildElements');
  },

  processChildElements: function() {
    // do here what you want with the DOM
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually, ApplicationView does not seem to be the right place, it works for the very first request, but when you start rendering other templates after that, the hook does not fire. I defined didInsertElement on the particular view I want to execute code after rendering, and that works fine, but it would be nice if Ember had a generic hook for after all views rendered, on every transition.

Comment: @clueless, you mentioned `$(document).ready` so yes `ApplicationView` is for the very first request, for all other views you need to do the same I guess as you already commented. As far I know there is no built-in hook for when all views are rendered.

Comment: @clueless There is no equivalent for `$(document).ready`, because that would result in global Spaghetti code. You are supposed to put your jQuery logic into the View, that suits the task best.

Answer (score 0):

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  afterRender: function () {
    Ember.run.next(this, function () {
      // This will run one time, after the full initial render.
    });
  }
});
```